# Write SQL results back to same record

Tags: sql

I am using the following script to grab the value from DWNAME and split the value into 10 individuals values.  What I need to do after that is take those 10 values and write them back to the SAME record to the COLUMN values that are listed as the Aliases.  Is there a way to, within the same code, perform the record update?

```
WITH DOCUMENT_ID AS
  (SELECT 
    DWDOCID, 
    VALUE, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by DWDOCID Order by DWDOCID) AS RowNum
  FROM [dwdata].[dbo].[SUAM]
    CROSS APPLY
        STRING_SPLIT(DWNAME,'^')
    WHERE DWDOCID > '3071822' AND DOCUMENT_TYPE IS NULL
    )

SELECT DWDOCID,
    [1] AS DRAWER,
    [2] AS DOCID,
    [3] AS STUDENTNUMBER,
    [4] AS STUDENTID,
    [5] AS LASTNAME,
    [6] AS FIRSTNAME,
    [7] AS FIELD5,
    [8] AS DOCTYPE,
    [9] AS CREATEDATE,
    [10] AS DOCUMENTYEAR
FROM DOCUMENT_ID
PIVOT
(MAX(VALUE)
FOR RowNum in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])) AS PVT
```

Comment: Obviously you are not using MySql or SQLite. Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Simple update to your code

```
WITH DOCUMENT_ID AS
  (SELECT 
    DWDOCID, 
    VALUE, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by DWDOCID Order by DWDOCID) AS RowNum
  FROM [SUAM]
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(DWNAME,'^')
  WHERE DWDOCID > '3071822' AND DOCUMENT_TYPE IS NULL
    )
update suam
  set drawer=t.drawer,docid=t.docid,studentnumber=t.studentnumber,studentid=t.studentid
  ,lastname=t.lastname,firstname=t.firstname,field5=t.field5
  ,createdate=t.createdate,documentyear=t.documentyear
from suam s inner join
(
SELECT DWDOCID,
    [1] AS DRAWER,
    [2] AS DOCID,
    [3] AS STUDENTNUMBER,
    [4] AS STUDENTID,
    [5] AS LASTNAME,
    [6] AS FIRSTNAME,
    [7] AS FIELD5,
    [8] AS DOCTYPE,
    [9] AS CREATEDATE,
    [10] AS DOCUMENTYEAR
FROM DOCUMENT_ID
PIVOT
(MAX(VALUE)
FOR RowNum in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])) AS PVT
)t on s.dwdocid=t.dwdocid
```